# Regex c#: Last Name in an email to include only one hyphen

Tags: c#, regex

Friends,
I have a textbox, which takes firstname.Lastname for my organisation.
The last name may or may not include hyphen.If it includes, then it should appear,
1) Only once in last name
2) Not at the beginning of lastname
3) not at the end of last name

I have this Regex figured out

> ^(?!.{51})[a-zA-Z]+(?:[.][a-zA-Z-]+)?$

This includes "-" in last name. But will not satisfy above conditions.

Im still learning regex, and is taking time to figure out this.
Please help

-Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add one more nested group inside the last name part:

```
^(?!.{51})[a-zA-Z]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z]+(?:-[a-zA-Z]+)?)?$
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%28%3F!.%7B51%7D%29%5Ba-zA-Z%5D%2B%28%3F%3A%5C.%5Ba-zA-Z%5D%2B%28%3F%3A-%5Ba-zA-Z%5D%2B%29%3F%29%3F%5Cr%3F%24&i=Joe.Smith%0D%0AJoe.Doe-Smith%0D%0AJoe.Doe-%0D%0AJoe.-Doe&o=m)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.{51})` -  no more than 50 chars in the string requirement
- `[a-zA-Z]+` - 1+ ASCII letters
- `(?:\.[a-zA-Z]+(?:-[a-zA-Z]+)?)?` - an optional sequence of:

  - `\.` - a dot
  - `[a-zA-Z]+` -  1 or more ASCII letters
  - `(?:-[a-zA-Z]+)?`  - an optional sequence of:

    - `-`  -  a hyphen
    - `[a-zA-Z]+` - 1+ ASCII letters
- `$` - end of string.

To declare this pattern, use a verbatim string literal:

```
var pattern = @"^(?!.{51})[a-zA-Z]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z]+(?:-[a-zA-Z]+)?)?$";
```

To match any Unicode letters, use `\p{L}` instead of `[a-zA-Z]`.

Comment: Thnak you Thank you. Not just for the Solution, but for explaining and making it clear to understand for beginners like me.

Answer (score 0):

This is a somehow Quick and Dirty Solution.

`^(?!.{51})[a-zA-Z]+.{1}[a-zA-Z]{1,}-?[a-zA-Z]+$`

The first part of the string is still used from you. It seem to match just perfect.
My Addition `.{1}[a-zA-Z]{1,}-?[a-zA-Z]+` simply describes what happens next.

1. `[a-zA-Z]{1,}` makes sure that there is at least one charackter after the dot, so no "-" can be written as beginning.
2. `-?`just describes that there may be appear a "-" somewhere after the first characters has been written.
3. `[a-zA-Z]+` just says that there may come as many characters as the user want's. But not a "-" anymore.